# Docker net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Tags: docker, connection

I'm new on docker and I can't to understand why during docker pull on https://registry-1.docker.io I have this error: **net/http: TLS handshake timeout**.

Once I got this message I lose a part of my connection so I can only restart to unlock the situation.

I'm using docker 3.5.2 with wsl2 (ubuntu)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the proxy server edit `~/.docker/config.json` file and configure your proxy server:

```
{
 "proxies": {
   "default": {
     "httpProxy": "http://proxy.example.com:3128",
     "httpsProxy": "https://proxy.example.com:3129",
     "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example.org,127.0.0.0/8"
   }
 }
}
```

See [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/).

Comment: Hi, please add supporting information, explaining why proxy  servers are causing the problem...